# Selfmade Linked List extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

For educational purposes I had to develop a very basic selfmade Linked List in C#. It is only supposed to Have the ability to add elements and a few other tidbits. My main problem is that compared to the frameworks collections Adding and Enumerating operations are real slow, am I doing something wrong or can you just not do any better with managed code?

(Enumerating over 1000000 elements takes about 500 miliseconds and Appending 1000000 elements takes around 700 miliseconds)

```
internal class GenericBuffer<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    protected class BufferNode
    {
        internal T Buffered { get; set; }
        internal BufferNode Next { get; set; }

        internal BufferNode(T buffered)
        {
            this.Buffered = buffered;
            this.Next = null;
        }
    }

    protected BufferNode First { get; set; }
    protected BufferNode Last { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; protected set; }

    internal GenericBuffer()
    {
        this.First = null;
        this.Last = null;
        this.Count = 0;
    }

    internal void Append(T toBuffer)
    {
        if (this.First == null)
        {
            this.First = this.Last = new BufferNode(toBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Last.Next = new BufferNode(toBuffer);
            this.Last = this.Last.Next;
        }

        this.Count++;
    }

    internal bool PullHead(out T head)
    {
        if (this.First == null)
        {
            head = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        else if (this.First == this.Last)
        {
            head = this.Last.Buffered;
            this.First = null;
            this.Last = null;
            this.Count--;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            head = this.First.Buffered;
            this.First = this.First.Next;
            this.Count--;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var currentNode = this.First;

        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            yield return currentNode.Buffered;
            currentNode = currentNode.Next;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Thanks for any advice and tips you have on that subject. :)

Comment: This sort of question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com. Either way, what collections did you compare this with? T[]? List<T>? These don't allocate node objects, so adding takes less time and memory - in most cases, memory has already been allocated beforehand. They store their content contiguously, so fetching the next item only requires incrementing a pointer, not following a reference to another node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `List<T>` is available online, along with most of the .NET framework, via the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs), so I highly recommend you check that out and compare it to your implementation.

In general, managed languages are designed to make higher level functionality easier to implement and maintain, the tradeoff being that optimizations are more difficult to implement, and other wise simple, lower-level pointer interactions like linked lists can get much more heavy in managed code.

Also, please be sure to cite some of the comparative times seen with the other implementations you've tested against.